# Toggle Downloading Button in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have an app which generates a csv file to download. The process takes some time, and I'm trying to display a downloading..... message in the meanwhile. Based on some other answers on SO, I have figured out how to display that message when I'm trying to render a plot/table, but in this case I'm just trying to download a file. Currently, this is what I have-

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)

jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}" # Define the js method that resets the page

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),
    tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "
                               #loadmessage {
                         position: fixed;
                         bottom: 0px;
                         right: 0px;
                         width: 20%;
                         padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
                         text-align: center;
                         font-weight: bold;
                         font-size: 150%;
                         color: white;
                         background-color: #034f84;
                         z-index: 10;}")),
    conditionalPanel(condition="$('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",
                     tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage")),

    downloadButton('dwd', "Download!"),
    textOutput("text"),
    actionButton("calc", 'Calculate'),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
    dataTableOutput("tbl")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$reset, {js$reset()}) # Reset the app


    output$text <- renderText({
      if(input$rnd > 0)
        paste("loading....")
    })

    output$dwd <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){
        paste0("Iris.csv")
      },
      content = function(file){
        Sys.sleep(3)
        write.csv(iris, file)
      }
    )

    observeEvent(input$calc, {
      Sys.sleep(3)
      output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(iris)
      )
    })

    observe({
      if(is.null(input$rnd)){
        runjs("
              var click = 0;
              Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)
              var dwnldBtn = document.getElementById('dwd')
              dwnldBtn.onclick = function() {click += 1; Shiny.onInputChange('rnd', click)}
              click = 0;
              ")      
      }
    })
  }
)
```

This displays the loading... message when I first download the file, but then the message persists. Is there any way that the Loading... message which is displayed during rendering the table can be displayed when trying to download the file too?

Thanks!